# How to summ all posts in the forum/index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I have some trouble and idont know how to realise is it.
I have 3 models:  Forum, Topic, Post
And i should show summ of all posts in forum/index

## Forum_controller

```
def index
    @forums = Forum.all
end
```

## Forum/index.html.slim

```
- @forums.each do |forum|           
    tr.dotted                      
        td.yach 
            = image_tag('forumico.png') 
            u = link_to forum.name, forum_path(forum)   
            br
            p = forum.desc
        td = forum.topics.count 
        td = forum.topics.post.count  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

## error

```
undefined method `post' for #<Topic
```

## relationships

```
class Forum 
  has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy

class Post 
 belongs_to :topic
 belongs_to :user

class Topic
 belongs_to :forum
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a through relationship

```
class Forum 
  has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :topics
```

You should then be able to:

```
forum.posts.count
```

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand that comment.

Comment: i am sorry, its i founded error at other part of my code, It is dont  applies to you

Answer (score 0):

If you need a count of posts you can just change the following

```
- @forums.each do |forum|           
    tr.dotted                      
        td.yach 
            = image_tag('forumico.png') 
            u = link_to forum.name, forum_path(forum)   
            br
            p = forum.desc
        td = forum.topics.count 
        td = forum.topics.map(&:posts).flatten.count
```

Answer (score -1):

use [sum method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum)

Calculates the sum of values on a given column. The value is returned with the same data type of the column, 0 if there's no row.

```
Post.sum(:column)
```

Comment: OP wants to count a post, not an attributes.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.